# PHP Mail function sent duplicate email

Tags: php, html-email

I build a form with validation for reCaptcha and my setup are sent email in duplicate and get spammed from the Office.

What is my mistake?

Everything is working fine except the fact is when a form is filled, we received 2 email at the time.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {

    $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
    $privatekey = "******";

    $response = file_get_contents($url."?secret=".$privatekey."&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
    $data = json_decode($response);

    if(isset($data->success) AND $data->success==true){

        $to = "whois@sent.this";
        $emailfrom = $_POST['email'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $nom = $_POST['nom'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $subject = "Formulaire de Contact Web  ";
        $commentaire = $_POST['commentaire'];

        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-to: $emailfrom";

        $message = "
         <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\">
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>Appel de service  (rempli sur le site internet)</title>
        <meta charset=\"UTF-8\">
        <style type=\"text/css\">
        h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
            font-family: Cambria, \"Hoefler Text\", \"Liberation Serif\", Times, \"Times New Roman\", serif;
            color: #272727;
        }
        </style>
        </head>
        <body>
        <h2 style=\"font-size: 1.25em; font-family: Gotham, ʼHelvetica Neueʼ, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;\">Vous avez re&ccedil;u une demande de contact sur votre site internet. </h2>
        <br>
        <table width=\"500\" border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"5\" cellspacing=\"2\">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td colspan=\"2\" align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\" bgcolor=\"#84BDEC\"><h3>Formulaire de contact Copiscan.com</h3></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width=\"155\" align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\" bgcolor=\"#D5D5D5\">Nom</td>
              <td width=\"313\" align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\">$nom</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width=\"155\" align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\" bgcolor=\"#D5D5D5\">Téléphone</td>
              <td width=\"313\" align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\">$phone</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\" bgcolor=\"#D5D5D5\">Adresse courriel</td>
              <td align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\">$email</td>
            </tr>
            <tr bgcolor=\"#D5D5D5\">
              <td colspan=\"2\" align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\">Commentaire :</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td height=\"75\" colspan=\"2\" align=\"left\" valign=\"top\">$commentaire</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        </body>
        </html>
         ";
// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 

        // so on...all your mail parameters here


        if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
                    header('Location: contactez-nous.php?CaptchaPass');

        }else{
            echo "mail could not be sent";
        }
    }else{
                header('Location: contactez-nous.php?CaptchaFail');
    }

}else{
    header('Location: contactez-nous.php?CaptchaError');

}

?>
```

Comment: you are calling it twice. once after comment `//always set ...` and then once more in `if`

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't know that. I've limited in Javascript and PHP Knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

double function call `mail`

```
// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 

        // so on...all your mail parameters here
        if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
```

try this one:

```
// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$mailOk = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 

        // so on...all your mail parameters here
        if($mailOk){
```

Or other way around:

```
// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
// Remove this line --> mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 

        // so on...all your mail parameters here
        if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))){
```

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 
    // so on...all your mail parameters here


    if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
                header('Location: contactez-nous.php?CaptchaPass');

    }else{
        echo "mail could not be sent";
    }
```

The second mail(...) inside the if statement not only evaluates whether the mail was successfully sent, but also sends the mail. So remove the first mail(...) and keep the one inside the if statement.

Answer (score 1):

The first email it send when it reach at

```
// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

and the 2nd email when it reach at check

```
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
```

just remove the first mail function and it will solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's appreciated.